# How to center a scrollable image that is larger than the screen

Tags: javascript, css

I'd like to make an image viewer that centers an image regardless of how big it is and allows scrolling to view the entire image.

The problem I'm running into is that, while centering images smaller than the container is easy, when they're larger tranform I'm doing positions the image off the right and top of the screen.

Here is the fiddle that has some fixup javascript to make it work: http://jsfiddle.net/d3y0b8bd/

The code below will work for smaller images (e.g. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/meta/0/08/Wikipedia-logo-v2_1x.png)

But for larger, the translate(-50%, -50%) transform will translate the image past the left and top margins of its parent.

```
.lightboxRoot {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    /*aesthetic*/
    background-color: red;
}
.lightboxImg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    /*aesthetic*/
    background-color: blue;
}
```

html:

```
<div class="lightboxRoot">
    <div class="lightboxImg">
        <img id="imgElt" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/Cute_beagle_puppy_lilly.jpg"></img>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, in retrospect kind of silly: Just make a containing div that can't get any larger than the parent element, and make sure that it has the overflow property set so it gets the scrollbars. then the image inside can get is big as it wants: http://jsfiddle.net/abrady0/d3y0b8bd/2/

```
.lightboxRoot {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /*aesthetic*/
    background-color: red;
}
.lightboxContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    max-width: 90%;
    max-height: 90%;
    overflow: auto;
    /*aesthetic*/
    background-color: blue;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="lightboxRoot">
    <div class="lightboxContainer">
        <div>
            <img id="imgElt" src="foo"></img>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

one thing to fix in this case is that I'd still like the div's scroll centered with pure CSS, but this is a good first step.

Answer (score 3):

[here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d3y0b8bd/4/) in which JS is updating the position of `scrollTop` and `scrollLeft`, so to set the scroll to center of img.

Comment: thanks! I should clarify I'd love to do it with pure CSS but I don't think there's a way to do that (I saw something about using anchors but it seemed inelegant)